# Need J/Link values returned in 1D instead of 2D format (i.e., not exponents, fractions, on multiple lines)

Tags: java

The following code shows how default KernelLink values are sent back to Java in 2D text form. Which becomes a heap-big mess in an array of exponential values, since all the exponents are printed first in one line...followed by the base values...messing up all their alignments.

How might it be possible to convert the return values to 1D format, e.g., 5.*^-10?

```
import com.wolfram.jlink.*;
public class TestJLink {
public static void main(String[] argv) {
    KernelLink ml = null;
    try {
        ml = MathLinkFactory.createKernelLink(argv);
    } catch (MathLinkException e) {
        System.out.println("Fatal error opening link: " +        e.getMessage());
        return;
    }
    try {
        ml.discardAnswer();
        String strResult = ml.evaluateToOutputForm("<<1Dreturn.m", 0);
        System.out.println("\n" + strResult + "\n");
    } catch (MathLinkException e) {
        System.out.println("MathLinkException occurred: " +  e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        ml.close();
    }
  }
}
```

The 1Dreturn.m file is:

```
Subscript[\[Gamma], E] = UnitSimplify[Quantity[None,     "ElectronMass"*"SpeedOfLight"^2]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's all right there in the name: `evaluateToOutputForm`.

If you want it `InputForm`, use `evaluateToInputForm`.

This is all documented in the [tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/JLink/tutorial/WritingJavaProgramsThatUseTheWolframLanguage.html).